# Clarification regarding working of EOF when data is not read from any external file

Tags: c

In this code from K&R

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
     putchar(c);
}
```

It has been mentioned that

> When the end of the input is finally reached, the `while` terminates and so
>   does `main`.

The above program terminates when **EOF** is encountered but even when the data in the stream ends, the EOF condition is not met and the looping continues.

Since there is no **file** involved from where the text can be read, I believe that the **EOF** must be signalled externally by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - Am I correct that it should be signalled externally (manually) and it wouldn't happen on its own even when the data in the stream will finish? The book says it will terminate when the input will end.

NOTE: The OS is centos being used on virtual box, hence the commands need <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> as well.

Comment: Yes, ctrl+D closes `stdin` and when you are reading from `stdin`, `getchar()` would then return `EOF`.

Comment: what is your question? `stdin` is of type `FILE *` like other standard files.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The question is whether EOF has to be signalled manually or will it happen on its own after reading say "Hello" as there isn't anything left in stream to be read.

Comment: Note also that when you chain commands with a pipe, `stdin` is also closed when no more inputs is available. Let's say your program is `./a`, then `cat /etc/resolv.conf | ./a` would also close `stdin` when `cat` ends. And `./a < /etc/resolv.conf` would also close `stdin` when the last character in the file is read.

Comment: Of course it has to be signaled manually. There is no way for the system to know if there is nothing more in the stream because the user has finished or if it is because the user is a slow typist.

Comment: @SiggiSv try entering an entire line as input, press enter and then revisit your comment.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus I have tried entering an entire line as input, press enter, input the next line, press enter, stand up, get me some coffee, gone back and entered some more lines as input, pressing enter after each one. Until I manually signal `EOF` the system does not know if I have finished or if I want to enter more lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EOF` ("end-of-file") doesn't actually have any direction correlation to a "file" - it's not something that's present at the end of a file. It's just a state that says "there's no more to read from this stream" and typically returned by a number of I/O functions.

So whether you are reading from a file, pipe, or any other I/O device, its (`EOF`) meaning is the same: nothing more to read from that stream.

When you are reading from the terminal via `stdin` stream, there's no such EOF state (pressing return key is NOT the "end-of-file" condition - it's end of line and would input `\n` char to your program) because you could keep on inputting data. So you'd generate `EOF` by using the key sequence <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> windows) on a unix-like system. So to answer your question, yes, you would have to generate it yourself in your (K&R) program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `EOF` has to be signaled manually.

The main reason is that there is no way for the system to know if there is nothing more in the stream because the user has finished or if it is because the user is a slow typist